# .sty suffix (extension) for LaTeX packages

Tags: packages, texmf, latex-misc

I understand that the suffix `.cls` stands for **classes**.

Then, why **packages** don't have the suffix `.pkg`, but rather have `.sty`?

Comment: Because they are used to style things...?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Style things? Like `lastpage` and many other are (not) doing, for example ... :-/ And why not `\usestyle` then?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

LaTeX 2.09 did not have the distinction; everything was called `sty`les.

```
 \documentstyle[12pt,longtable]{article}
```

When we made LaTeX2e, there were relatively few "main document styles". The standard ones (article/report/book) accounted for the vast majority of documents. As they were part of the core distribution,  changing those to be "classes" was not too hard.

The majority of "style files" worked unchanged or with only minor updates with 2e, so forcing a filename change would have been too disruptive, but "style" seemed to be the wrong name, so "package" was introduced.

Answer (score 16):

This is an historical artifact.

In LaTeX 2.09 there weren't "document classes", but "document styles", with extension `.sty`: `book.sty`, `article.sty` and so on.

Additional "packages" were loaded as options to `\documentstyle` and they needed to have the `.sty` extension as well.

When LaTeX2e introduced document classes (extension `.cls`), the `.sty` extension was kept because some of the additional packages could be used out of the box simply with `\usepackage`. Maintaining two possible extensions is cumbersome (and LaTeX2e had severe limitations on memory usage).